# WCF RIA Entity Using Load Operation; How to Get Latest Database changes

Tags: c#, wcf, ria

this is a follow up from the following question
[WCF RIA : LoadOperation Not Refreshing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849487/wcf-ria-loadoperation-not-refreshing-data)

```
LoadOperation<Clarifications> ClarificationsLP = context.Load(context.GetClarificationsQuery().Where(o => o.ProjectID == ((App)Application.Current).Project.ProjectID).OrderBy(o => o.RaisedOn), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, false); ClarificationsLP.Completed += delegate
        {};
```

The code above works fine, it will return me any changes that may occur in the database outside of my application. Great! However it only returns me the new changes...what if an Item was deleted? How can I deal with this? This is an issue for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if other application is deleting registrys, and you want to refresh it, so you need to **clear the cache** entitys and do the load operation.